# Is it possible to trigger a module loading in Angular 2.1 (Angular Router 3.1.0)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've been experimenting with Angular 2.1 and module lazy loading and preloading. So far I have been able to do the common things and use the different strategies, or also define a basic custom one as explained in the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#custom-preloading) and in [this post](https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-preloading-modules-ba3c75e424cb#.uncujwfda) from Victor Savkin.

But, is there any way of preloading a module triggering this loading after an specific event or an interaction on a component (say a click or somethink like that and before navigating to it)?

Is it possible to inject something more interesting than a boolean/number/string value to the data parameter of a *Routes* (that will be added to the *RouterModule.forRoot* for example) and consuming it when you define your own custom *PreloadingStrategy*?

app.routes.ts

```
[
  {
    path: 'moduleA',
    loadChildren: './moduleA.module',
    data: {preload: true}
  },
  {
    path: 'moduleB',
    loadChildren: './moduleB.module'
  }
]
```

...

```
export class PreloadSelectedModulesList implements PreloadingStrategy {
  preload(route: Route, load: Function): Observable<any> {
    return route.data && route.data.preload ? load() : of(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good question - any ideas anyone?

Comment: I think that this article answers at least a part of the question: https://johnpapa.net/predictive-preloading-of-your-angular-bundles/